# Is there any way to see the tree element in xml.etree.cElementTree in running time?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Im using `xml.etree.cElementTree` data structure to build an xml file.
But im having trouble to keep track on him while i'm running the program.

Is there any way i can see all of the tree in debug mode ?

Im using it like this :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element("base")
CompilationEngine().compile_statements(root)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
out_file = open(OUTPUT_TEST_PATH, 'w')
tree.write(OUTPUT_TEST_PATH)
```

Comment: How about using [`ET.tostring(root)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring)?

Comment: That would be really helpful.
But there is any way to get the debug information ?
because the string representation is really big

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "debug information". I cannot run your code and I don't know what it does. What is `CompilationEngine`?